# Is there a list of possible errors in Knex.js?

Tags: node.js, knex.js

I was wondering if anyone knew where I can get a list of possible errors that can be returned by the Knex.js ORM, I need this so I can map these errors and return my custom messages.

Thank you very much!

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

If you're thinking about specific database error code, probably you have to map it by yourself.
I'm doing it like this::

```
function mapErrors (error: DbErrorType) {
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'ER_DUP_ENTRY':
      throw new DuplicatedEntryError(error.sqlMessage);
    default:
      throw new DbError(error.sqlMessage);
  }
}
```